# 'Generator' object has no attribute 'shape' when trying to training model on data from generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I have been trying to train a simpletf.keras.Sequential() model with the help of a custom generator. According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) I can pass a generator to model.fit() like so:

```
model.fit(x=generator, epochs=5)
```

However I keep getting the following error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(x=generator, epochs=5)

File ~\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:885, in GeneratorDataAdapter.__init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    878     except NotImplementedError:
    879         # The above call may fail if the model is a container-like class
    880         # that does not implement its own forward pass (e.g. a GAN or
    881         # VAE where the forward pass is handled by subcomponents).  Such
    882         # a model does not need to be built.
    883         pass
--> 885 self._first_batch_size = int(tf.nest.flatten(peek)[0].shape[0])
    887 def _get_tensor_spec(t):
    888     # TODO(b/226395276): Remove _with_tensor_ranks_only usage.
    889     return type_spec.type_spec_from_value(t)._with_tensor_ranks_only()

AttributeError: 'SequenceGenerator' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The model I was trying to train:

```
# Create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,
                               input_shape=(gen_config["num_steps"], 40,),
                               return_sequences=False,
                               stateful=False,
                               ))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

#compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )
```

The generator I use to yield the inputs:

```
class SequenceGenerator():

    def __iter__(self): 

        # set seed everytime that generator is restarted
        if self.seed:
            np.random.seed(self.seed)

        # set chunk_index, batch_index
        self.chunk_index = 0
        self.batch_index = 0

        # set chunk_indexer
        self._chunk_indexer_setup()  # self._chunk_indexer_reset()
        self.no_total_chunks = len(self._chunk_indexer)
        self._no_features = self.pipeline_function.no_features

        # Start iteration
        if len(self._chunk_indexer) > 0:

            # Infinite iteration
            while True:

                # Fill pool of chunks if
                # (1) x_ts is not yet initialized
                # (2) self.x_ts is not enough to feed two batches
                if self.x_ts is None or len(self.x_ts) < self.batch_size * 2:
                    chunk_pool = self.get_chunk_pool()

                    if len(chunk_pool) > 0:
                        x, y, flag = [np.vstack(array) for array in zip(*chunk_pool)]
                        x_ts, y_ts = self._get_timeseries(x, y, flag)

                        # 1st iteration of generator
                        if self.x_ts is None:
                            self.x_ts, self.y_ts = x_ts, y_ts
                        # Iterations after 1st, i.e. observations exists: just append
                        else:
                            self.x_ts = np.concatenate((self.x_ts, x_ts))
                            self.y_ts = np.concatenate((self.y_ts, y_ts))

                # if x_ts contains at least one batch, yield batch
                # if generator is exhausted, yield empty batch
                if len(self.x_ts) >= self.batch_size or self.exhausted:
                    yield self.x_ts[:self.batch_size], self.y_ts[:self.batch_size]
```

The generator outputs a tuple of length 2 (as specified in "Unpacking behavior for iterator-like inputs" in the documentation), consisting of two numpy arrays.
The shape of x is (32, 100, 40) and that of y is (32, 1).
I am cofused about what shape attribute model.fit() expects the generator to provide.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Despite the name, `SequenceGenerator` isn't a generator. It's only an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). TF seems to care about that distinction.